# No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>

Tags: azure-devops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kYwT.png)Hello guys I'm facing this error when try to deploy a release pipeline on azure:
Error: No package found with specified pattern: `D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>` Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

I already googled it and found a couple of posts even here in stack overflow but, the thing is that my case is different I already added this part to my YAML file:

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kYwT.png)

but still having the same error

Comment: Are you using a multi-stage yaml pipeline?

Comment: you forgot the image

Comment: Hello Calidus thx for reply, no is not a multi-stage pipeline I just added the link from the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because the artifact this `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task generated is not a truly `.zip` file.

To make your deploy task work, here has one work around you can consider :

Add one [Archive Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) before this `deploy` task to pack out one `zip` file. Just configure it like this:

[image]

For **deploy task**, take `Azure app service deploy task` as example, just need keep deployed package path as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip` will be okay. They are all representing same path in Release pipeline.

Comment: Thx a lot, I added the task as you mention :- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive Artifact'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: $(System.DefaltWorkingDirectory)
    includeRootFolder: true  
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true  but now  the error in the log says Zip warning name not matched $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Comment: thx @Merlin Liang now I'm facing this error in the log                                                     
   Zip warning name not matched $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory, any idea?

Comment: you right @Merlin Lang just a couple of things I changed at the end like root folder to archive  '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'  and path to publish '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'   thanks a lot mate